# How to find all places where a class is used in a field definition in intellij?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, ide

Given a class definition, I can easily find all places where it is used in several ways, in a long list with some filtering options.

But what I want is to find fields of the type I am interested in, that is, **I want look at a class definition and answer the question "Which classes have a field of this type?"**

I am using Intellij IDEA 2023.2.5 with Java17, but I would appreciate answers even if they use different tools or work in different languages.
A perfect answer would also find fields of a supertype of the class I am looking for but the simple answer of finding fields of the exact type is good enough.

Comment: Please do not encourage "AI" spammers by upvoting or accepting their answers.

Comment: Also I suspect the answer to your question is "structured search." It doesn't make a lot of sense to me so I can't directly answer your question, but the few times I've had to do similar searches that's been the recommended answer.

Comment: @miken32 I felt conflicted accepting it. It did answer my question perfectly and the gpt-ish wordy essay-style did not distract from the good part, so either the genAI-user got lucky or double-checked and verified the AI-answer. That's why I asked him to shorten it. I am very much against AI-answers because they are almost always horrible, but I would be happy with the answer if the date on it was 2019, so is it really spam?

Comment: @miken32 Thank you for recommending Structured Search to me, that does seem worth checking out for advanced searches but my use-case is perfectly covered by what intellij offers out-of-the-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Find Usages" solves the problem. Activate with `Alt`+`F7` (Windows) or `Alt`+`Shift`+`F7` (Gnome) or `⌥Opt`+`F7` (Mac) or through the right-click-context-menu to find usages of the class under the cursor. The usages will be grouped, and one of those groups is "Field declaration".

More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-highlight-usages.html

Comment: I removed my accepted-badge from the first answer because it is likely AI-generated and wrote something that is more concise and has the correct shortcuts taken from the documentation.